# Show $\sum_{y\ \in\ Y\ \ } \sum_{x\ \in \ X\ :\ x \le \ y} \left( \left(\frac{1}{6-x+1} \right) \left(\frac{2(6-x+1)-1}{36} \right) \right) = 1$

Tags: probability-theory, summation

> Two fair dice are rolled. Find the joint probability mass function of
>   $X$ and $Y$ when $X$ is the smallest and $Y$ is the largest value
>   obtained on the dice.

Reasoning this out (but leaving out the possibly irrelevant details),  my work shows

$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{x\ \in\  X\ \ } \sum_{y\ \in \ Y\ :\ x \le \ y} \left( \left(\frac{1}{6-x+1} \right) \left(\frac{2(6-x+1)-1}{36} \right) \right) \\
& = \sum_{y\ \in\  Y\ \ } \sum_{x\ \in \ X\ :\ x \le \ y} \left( \left(\frac{1}{6-x+1} \right) \left(\frac{2(6-x+1)-1}{36} \right) \right) \\
& = 1
\end{align}$$

which seems to imply we have found the PMF as asked in the problem, but I only know the last line follows because [Mathematica said so](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B+%281%2F%286-x%2B1%29%29%28%282%286-x%2B1%29-1%29%2F36%29%2C+%7By%2C1%2C6%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C1%2Cy%7D%5D). How can we show that this double summation is indeed equal to $1$ by hand?

Comment: Add up the fractions? $\frac{11}{216}+\left(\frac{11}{216}+\frac{9}{180}\right)+\cdots$

Comment: @Steve Kass, nice, but  for more general problems (where the possibilities aren't limited to the sides of 6-sided dice), how would you show the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Steve said, add up the fractions since there is only a really finite space $|6 \times 6$ to consider.